# dynamically resize images w/ jquery

Tags: jquery, image, resize

I'm using a script that uses DD's Ultimate Fade-in Slideshow:
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex14/fadeinslideshow.htm

It uses jquery, and I would like to resize the images to the slideshow size.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
fadeSlideShow.routines={

getSlideHTML:function(imgelement){
    var layerHTML=(imgelement[1])? '<a href="'+imgelement[1]+'" target="'+imgelement[2]+' ">\n' : '' //hyperlink slide?
    layerHTML+='<img src="'+imgelement[0]+'" style="border-width:0; width: 440px;" />\n'
```

I just added a width to the style call...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to animate the size of the images you can use:

```
jQuery('#imgID').animate({
  width: newwidth,
  height: newheight
});
```

or if you don't want to animate the resizing just use

```
jQuery('#imgID').css({'width':'newwidth', 'height':'newheight'});
```

newheight and newwidth would be integers of whatever dimensions you want to give it. i.e. 100px x 200px